# Redbean 3.2.x - Custom Mapping

Tags: php, redbean

I am trying to implement custom mapping for a database I am using that was pre-setup with primary key fields like `tablename_id` instead of just `id`.

I gleaned this from the 2.0 manual:

```
class MyBeanFormatter implements RedBean_IBeanFormatter {
    public function formatBeanID($type) {
        return $type.'_id';
    }
}
R::$writer->setBeanFormatter( new MyBeanFormatter );
```

In 3.0, there is no interface `RedBean_IBeanFormatter` and no function `formatBeanID`.  The 3.0 manual, doesn't provide a lot to go on for this.  Any help would

Comment: I am 90% sure this cannot be done in 3.0 as of yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom mapping is no longer supported in 3.0.
RedBeanPHP 3 and higher require tables to map 1-to-1 to bean types.
This is part of the design philosophy of RedBeanPHP. It might be less useful for existing projects but I believe it keeps database mapping more maintainable in the end. This decision also allows RB to provide lots of power features, like deep-copy and exportAll while being relatively light-weight and fast.

Comment: I agree.  I am working on an existing project.  I would make those changes to allow for more flexibility, however the project is Java and I am not the one handling that.  I am just trying to create a connector for easy backend access.  Oh well.  I am just doing plain SQL and it works just fine.  Thanks for your response Gabor.  I love the product and am using it whenever I can.